# Select Same Stroke OR Color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I have an SVG (converted to AI) with red lines, red rectangles (with null stroke colors), blue lines, and blue rectangles (with null stroke colors). I can use Select > Same > Stroke Color to select all of the red lines, or Select > Same > Fill Color to select all of the red rectangles. I'm looking for a way to select ALL of the red lines and the red rectangles, whether that color is defined for the stroke or the fill. A method that can also select all text with a red color attribute would be idea.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you first group objects with the same stroke and then select/group objects with the same fill? I am not sure you could do both at the same time, maybe there is a way to do this with a script. Is there a reason why you cannot do it in 2 steps?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why do you actually want to do this?  What is the goal? Are you just trying to change the colours?  If so, you could use Edit > Colors > Recolor Artwork.

Comment: I am importing and editing SVGs generated by another application. The red and blue objects are already part of multilayered groups that include both colors. I want to be able to move or modify the red objects across all groups. @AndrewH's two step procedure could work, if I either remember or record how far I move the red lines and then apply the same transformation to the red boxes. Hope that helps.

Comment: In that case, then I think Andrew's suggestion  is probably your best bet. Maybe ungroup everything first so there are no groups left,  then do a select same fill , group those, then do another select same stroke, and group those, then group both groups as one. Then you can move as a whole.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the existing groups for other purposes. But it that is the only way I will make it work. As a tangential question, is there a way to aggregate objects in a way that is orthogonal to "groups"? For example, could objects 1A, 2A, 1B, and 2B be grouped (`Ctrl + G`) into groups 1 and 2, but also have some sort of selector/handle A and B so I could quickly select everything in group 1 (1A and 1B) or everything with handle A (1A and 2A)? I can post this question separately if that is preferable.

Comment: You can make a saved selection instead of a group (using **Select -> Save Selection**) . Or you can select via script.

Comment: Groups can be nested, but you can't have something in two separate groups at the same time.  Joojaa's idea of saving the selection sounds interesting.

Comment: Saving selections was immensely helpful. I still had to transform the lines and rectangles separately, as I couldn't figure out how to merge two saved selections, but clicking on the saved selection's name was much easier than doing Select > Same > Stroke Color over and over. The list of saved selections might get a bit cumbersome if you have dozens of them saved, but for my purposes it was great.

Comment: If one of the two classes of objects CAN be combined into a Group, you can select both classes in just 2 steps (after making the group and saved selections). 0.1) Make a Group (`Ctrl + G`) with one class. 0.2) Make a saved selection with the other class (__Select > Same > Stroke xxx__). 1) Select the saved selection (__Select > <selection name>__). 2) `Shift` click on an object in the grouped class. @joojaa, this was essentially your idea, if you want to post this as an answer.